# Error with keras using TensorFlow as backend

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm at the beginning of my project and I've just imported the packages that I need:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

Obviously both TensorFlow and keras are already installed. Anyway, if I run the code I get this error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.
.
.
.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\franc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-
  File "c:\users\franc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
ImportError: cannot import name 'context' from 'tensorflow.python.eager' (C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\__init__.py) 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\franc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2040, in showtraceback
    stb = value._render_traceback_()
AttributeError: 'ImportError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\franc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1101, in get_records
    return _fixed_getinnerframes(etb, number_of_lines_of_context, tb_offset)
  .
  .
  .
  File "c:\users\franc\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . _api.v2 import audio
ImportError: cannot import name 'audio' from 'tensorflow_core._api.v2' (C:\Users\franc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tensorflow_core\_api\v2\__init__.py)
```

I really don't know how to fix this problem, I've cheked many web sites to follow a correct installetion of the two packages but with no result. I did a correct installation but I still have this error.

Comment: Do you have these [things](https://keras.io/backend/) alright?

Comment: yes,i've installed both

Comment: Facing similar problem - ```ImportError: cannot import name 'context' from 'tensorflow.python.eager'```. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Did you overcome this in anyway? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try keras which comes with tensorflow. This keras uses only tensorflow as backend, which is what you need:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tf.keras import Sequential
from tf.keras.layers import Dense
```

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/overview

Comment: ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.